# What are some specific techniques to keep the daily Stand-up productive?

Tags: daily-scrum

What are some specific examples that help make a daily scrum productive. I understand that in a daily Scrum meeting the basic questions reviewed are:

1. What did you do yesterday?
2. What are your plans today?
3. What obstacles do you have in your work now?

In the daily Scrum dialogue what techniques have you found that are best for keeping things focused and moving toward productive work? Thanks.

Comment: Scrum is not just vocabulary. Why don't you get a good book and read that? If you want to make Scrum Master your new job, 20$ and 2 hours should be acceptable to get to know what you should know about it.

Comment: Take a look at this article: [It's Not Just Standing Up: Patterns for Daily Standup Meetings](https://martinfowler.com/articles/itsNotJustStandingUp.html).

Comment: I believe the question, as is, seems like a [bad subjective question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), although it may become a good subjective question with some nurture.

Answer (score 1):

--- Start of Standup ---

Hi,

welcome to the stand-up, lets make this quick, answer these 3 questions only please.

Q1, What did you do yesterday
Q2, What do you plan to do today
Q3, Are there any blockers stopping you from doing your tasks.

OK Lets start...

Hey *insert name* do you wan to give your update?
(repeat for all team members)

Ok any one any thing else they'd like to talk about ?

No ?

Ok. Lets Go !

--- Ends ---

*NB - its important not to stick to the rules too rigidly, if communication is flowing great, let it flow, & just keep an eye out that it doesn't side track the meeting too much.*